# How to group the char stream in java 8?

Tags: java, string

I need your help with String Java Program

```
Input : aaabbaaeedddbbbb
Output : a3b2a2e2d3b4
```

by using Java 8, one interview asking me

by using Groupby,streams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method using streams.

- the regular expression splits between different characters
- the map appends the string character and its length.
- the collector joins the strings.

```
String s = "aaabbaaeedddbbbb";
String result = Arrays.stream(s.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)"))
        .map(str->str.charAt(0)+""+str.length())
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
        
System.out.println(result);
```

Prints

```
a3b2a2e2d3b4
```

Here is one way to do it using `groupingBy` and `streams` (as requested in your question). It applies the previous method of splitting the source string.

```
String result = Arrays.stream(s.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy((a) -> "result",
                Collectors.mapping(
                        str -> str.charAt(0) + ""
                                + str.length(),
                        Collectors.joining())))
        .get("result");
```

However, imo this is very kludgely and a better way may exist.  But even then, it is inferior to other methods and I don't know why an interviewer would ask this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Matcher#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-) for this purpose.

```
String str = "aaabbaaeedddbbbb";
String res = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1*").matcher(str)
     .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(1) + mr.group().length());
System.out.println(res);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/84vRDw)